# iOS Swift: Check string suffix

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of strings that are filenames in my app bundle. Some are PNGs others are MOVs. Is there a good method for checking the string suffix in Swift?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `hasSuffix` and `filter` methods, like this:

```
let files : [String] = ["quick.txt", "brown.mov", "fox.exe", "jumps.mov", "over.jpg", "the.txt", "lazy.mov", "dog.opt"]
let movs = files.filter{$0.hasSuffix(".mov")}
println(movs) // Prints [brown.mov, jumps.mov, lazy.mov]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in function `hasSuffix:`

For this and other examples, take a look at: http://ios-blog.co.uk/swift-tutorials/introduction-to-ios8-swift-series-strings/